# Laravel 5 поиск по массиву в запросе

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, laravel5

У меня в БД есть записи и в одной колонке есть массивы, вида `["1", "2", "3"]`
Хочу вывести например все записи, где в массиве присутствует цифра **2**.

Как мне это сделать?

Вот мой запрос:

```
$tasks = Task::select(['id', 'title', 'price', 'status', 'date'])
   ->where('category', 1)
   ->where('subcategory', $id) // нужно чтобы здесь искало в массиве $id
   ->where('status', '!=', 0)
   ->where('status', '!=', 6)
   ->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')
   ->paginate($taskcount);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$tasks = Task::select(['id', 'title', 'price', 'status', 'date'])
        ->where('category', 1)
        ->where('subcategory', 'like', "%\"$id\"%" ) // ищет переменную в массиве
        ->where('status', '!=', 0)
        ->where('status', '!=', 6)
        ->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')
        ->paginate($taskcount);

    return view('categories.bio')->with([
        'tasks' => $tasks
    ]);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$tasks = Task::select(['id', 'title', 'price', 'status', 'date'])
        ->where(['category' => 1, ['status', '!=', 0], ['status', '!=', 6]])
        ->whereIn('id', [1, 2, 3])
        ->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')
        ->paginate($taskcount);
    return view('categories.bio')->with([
        'tasks' => $tasks
    ]);
```

Comment: постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развернутые ответы. [edit]

Comment: Sers, а где поиск по колонке `subcategory`?